# Spirograph: correct wheel ratio and pen draw length?

Tags: math, design-patterns, trigonometry

What is the ratio between the wheel size and the pen draw length in order to complete one turn, in a spirograph. i.e a spirograph with :

3 sides = 1.5   : 4pi   (wheelratio :  pen length)
4 sides = 1.333 : 6
5 sides = 2.5   : 5

a)why do 1.2/10 and 6/2 both make a 6 side spirograph?
a)What is the ratio?
c)how do i make an octogon spirograph?

```
function  spiro (  N:float,k:int ): Vector3//spirograph loop, N=total points in loop, k=current loop
{   //wr,pr=wheel/pen ratio:        5,        3,        4,            6,        6,
    var wr:float[]=new float[10];wr[0]=2.5;wr[1]=1.5;wr[2]=1.33333;wr[3]=1.2;wr[4]=6;
    var pr:float[]=new float[10];pr[0]=5.0;pr[1]=4.0;pr[2]=6.00000;pr[3]=10; pr[4]=2;
    var vr = 4;
    var wheel=wr[vr];
    var theta =(1/N)*Mathf.PI *pr[vr]*k;
    var rtheta =theta*wheel;
    var small = (1-1/wheel);//
    var cx=Mathf.Cos(theta)*small;
    var cz=Mathf.Sin(theta)*small;
    var ex=Mathf.Cos(theta-rtheta)/wheel;
    var ez=Mathf.Sin(theta-rtheta)/wheel;

    return Vector3(cx+ex,0,cz+ez);
}
```

Comment: In code the simplest way of figuring the length is checking if any 2 segments are exactly the same and calling a return on the function.  Further research shows me that sin-cos spirographs are much more limited than 2d L-systems with no branches, for making spirographs... change the curve of the next point from 1-5 degrees in discreet steps, on xy, makes amazing spirographs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some very nice pictures on the MathWorld articles on [Spirographs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spirograph.html) and [Hypotrochoids](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypotrochoid.html) that make it much easier to picture what is happening.

### Ad Hoc Explanation

For a particular number of "sides", the ratio between the outer radius (R) and the inner radius (r) is fairly easy to work out. The distance from the center of the small circle to the "pen" determines how "lumpy" the sides of the shape are.

```
sides = R / r
```

It is instructive to look at the form of the equations, without the c code "getting in the way" for the eight sided sample requested. In Mathematica this can be written:

```
hypotrochoid[R_, r_, h_] := Function[t, {
   (R - r) Cos[t] + h Cos[(R - r) t/r],
   (R - r) Sin[t] - h Sin[(R - r) t/r]
   }]

ParametricPlot[hypotrochoid[1, 1/8, 1/40][t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image: hypotrochoid with 8 "sides"]

### Pen Draw Length

To calculate pen draw length, you need two pieces of information. 1) the period of the function and 2) the arc length of the curve throughout a single period.

There is a good explanation of the period of a hypotrochoid on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257895/calculate-the-period-of-an-hypotrochoid), but in the case you're describing the period will be 2 pi.  In the more general case if R and r are both [rational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) the period will be finite and a multiple of 2 pi.

You can find the pen draw length based on the expression for parametric curve [arc length](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Arc_length&section=3#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating)

[image: arclength equation]

Substituting in the hypotrochoid equation (and with some simplification and assuming the period is 2 pi) you end up with the expression for arc length:

[image: spirograph arclength]

By inspection, I believe with proper constraints on R, r and h you should be able to get an analytic solution (probably a family of [complete elliptic integrals](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EllipticE.html)). If you've got the values of R, r and h a good computer algebra system (CAS) will find a solution.

Regardless of whether you have a CAS, for nearly polygonal spirographs, the arc length equation is simple enough to solve using naive methods (Euler Integration).

Comment: Thankyou very much! i'll study it some more. i think my code version is less understandable because i have written the small wheel as 1-1/r.

Comment: Thanks again. The pen line length ratio seems to be fairly simple for every different case, a simple fraction or integer. There must be simple maths for the line length for all periodic shapes where the pen as on edge of small wheel, and perhaps a simple math as well if the pen is further from the edge... I hope i have a chance to figure it out one day! it should be easy when i try/ if someone else knows. It took me a while to write a spirograph code that worked, and somehow i have 1 - reciprocal wheel size that messes the input ratios, so i should rewrite same as you wrote...

Answer (score 0):

The length of the line of the pen for a spirograph with 8 sides, if the pen is on edge of small wheel, is 8 times the small wheel radius. Same for 6,5,4 etc.

polygons can also be drawn in trigonometry in this fashion:
http://1ucasvb.tumblr.com/post/42906053623/in-a-previous-post-i-showed-how-to-geometrically

here is a demonstration in Function Plotter.
https://functionplotter.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIoc2VjKCgyLzYpKmFzaW4oc2luKCg2LzIpKngpKSkpKnNpbih4KSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d